# Is it possible to control System Volume, and Get network information, Battery information on VB.Net with Mono

Tags: networking, mono, volume, battery, batterylevel

I was wondering if it was possible to be able to control/get the system volume, get network information (i.e is it a wired or wireless connection, name of network, etc.) and get battery information with VB.Net using Mono on Ubuntu 12.10? Thanks.

Comment: I have to ask; why would you use VB.Net for this? Most of the information you're after is easily obtainable through shell commands (bash).

Comment: I am creating a system information program, written in VB.Net and need to be able to get the System volume, etc. to be displayed inside the program. I know I can control it through the terminal but I want to be able to read it inside the program.

Comment: All right. it's probably easier to use a language with native integration with the operating system though, like Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class to call out to the shell and invoke the commands / get the information you require. There is an example [here](http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Execute-Shell-Commands-from-Net.html).

Comment: It worked, but is there any way to prevent the terminal from showing up on linux?

Comment: @TheRyan722 On Windows, setting the process `CreateNoWindow` and `WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` properties would work; on Linux I'm not so sure